# Errores personalizados de 400, 404 y otros

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

¿Como puedo personalizar los errores 404, 400 y otros en Laravel 5.6?

Tengo mis paginas de errores listas en la carpeta errors dentro de view

Comment: ¿en qué carpeta específica tienes las páginas de errores?

Comment: Carpeta View->errors y ahí tengo 400.blade.php, 403, 404, 500 y 503

Comment: Lo unico que tienes que hacer es, en el router o en un controlador en el que redirijas a alguna página, haces un try{}catch para comprobar siesa ruta existe antes de enviar, si te salta error, lo capturas y redireccionas a una vista de los errores que ya tienes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las páginas de error en **Laravel** deberías controlarlas a través de la clase  `App\Exceptions\Handler`, que se encarga de manejar todas las excepciones del framework. Dentro de esta clase tenemos dos métodos: `report` y `render`.

El método que nos interesa es `render`, que se encarga de convertir una excepción en una repuesta HTTP. Aquí es donde podemos definir nuestras respuestas personalizadas. Por ejemplo, para una respuesta al código de error **500**:

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($exception instanceof CustomException) {
        return response()->view('errors.500', [], 500);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Una forma mucho más dinámica de redirigir a tus páginas de error personalizadas y dar respuesta a las excepciones (errores) que se producen en tu aplicación sería la siguiente:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if($this->isHttpException($e)){
        if (view()->exists('errors.'.$e->getStatusCode()))
        {
            return response()->view('errors.'.$e->getStatusCode(), [], $e->getStatusCode());
        }
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Este fragmento de código comprueba que la excepción que se recibe sea HTTP y que la vista personalizada existe antes de redirigir al usuario. Todo esto teniendo en cuenta que las vistas están situadas en el directorio `views/errors/{code}`, como parece ser tu caso.

Espero haberte ayudado. Siempre puedes consultar la documentación oficial de Laravel que está muy bien explicado: [Error Handling en Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/errors).

Comment: Todo funciona en orden, muchas gracias, te pasaste.